# Advice on finding Sambo seminars?

Tags: recommendation, sambo

I like Sambo but unfortunately in my location I haven't found any available classes.

Can someone advise an (affordable) seminar (week or week-end long) for all levels that is run somewhere in Europe?

Comment: Are you looking for a recommendation on specific Sambo classes that might be available where you are, or a martial art similar to Sambo for you to look into?

Comment: Sambo classes but in seminar form (i mean 1 week or 1 week-end for example) because I am currently in Poznań and I din't find any Sambo classes on regular basis here

Comment: It is probably best to contact http://www.pzsambo.pl/ and ask - this style of question tends to be off topic here (as the answers will be very location specific).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because question is about locale specific shipping

Comment: I am sorry I didn't know Europe was too local